# Display Drupal 7 Custom Menu

Tags: menu, drupal-7

I created a custom menu, named "footer-link", and i created links under it.
How do i display it? Can someone  help me thanks!

Some snippet i tried

`menu_navigation_links('footer-link'), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'site-menu')) ));?>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Structure" on your admin panel. And then click on "Blocks".
You should see a list of blocks available. You will also see a block for your custom menu.

There you can select the region where you want your link to be displayed.

I hope this helps. It is a very simple question you asked. Im surprised noone's answered yet.